# missing method "to_yaml" in IronRuby

Tags: yaml, ironruby

I created my own ruby console using IronRuby engine, but I can't get to_yaml to work on any of my .net classes.

Did I missed anything?

```
person = Person.new
person.Name = 'John Doe'
person.Age = 26
puts person.to_yaml #does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like YAML isn't included by default at startup. Try running

```
require 'yaml'
```

first - it made your code work for me in iirb.

Comment: Thanks, now I need to tell my application to point it to an existing ruby directory :) but this is already a separate question :)